# Linux bash: Combine two csv files with different headers

Tags: linux, bash, csv

I've these two files

First:

```
a;b;c;d
1;2;3;4
```

Second:

```
d;e;f;g
4;5;6;7
```

And I need this result:

```
a;b;c;d;e;f;g
1;2;3;4;;;
;;;4;5;6;7
```

Is there any short way to do this in Linux?

EDIT: The headers/columns of each csv file can change and can contain duplicate columns.

EDIT 2: Hmpf. The linked question is totally different scenario and didn't answer my question.

Comment: What is the criteria for the merge? Do all lines have empty columns for the other file's headers?

Comment: @MarcB Not really. It seems there are empty values added.

Comment: @Olaf I wouldn't call it merge. I need to concat two csv files, "merge" the header and fill the new columns with empty values

Comment: @gongzhitaao: read the manpage for paste. there's a delimiters option so you can tell it to use something OTHER than a tab, e.g. `;`.

Comment: I'd recommend just doing this quickly in Python or Perl.  It's about ten lines of Python; three lines if you use Python's `pandas` library; and I don't know Perl but I'd expect about the same size.

Answer (score 2):

You can join the header columns and then adjust the remaining lines

```
head1=`head -1 file1.txt`
head2=`head -1 file2.txt`
echo "$head1;$head2"
sed -e 1d -e 's/$/;;;/' file1.txt
sed -e 1d -e 's/^/;;;/' file2.txt
```

Comment: Thank you. I've edited my question. The problem is, that the headers can change and can contain duplicate columns.

Comment: @Torben What happens, if the common column is not at the beginning/end, but somewhere in between, e.g. `a;b;c;d` and `e;c;f;g`?

Comment: This can happen, yes. Hoped there's a short way to do this in a bash script.

Comment: @Torben Well, you can do it of course, but it's not short. At least not, what I can come up with.